# How to make asynchronous MySQL operations with modular queries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, mysql-python, discord.py

I am currently working on a slightly complex discord bot for a community driven event.
The goal is to provide a simple webinterface where the clans can sign in and do everything they need to be able to do (like sign up for the event, view statistics, view teams, etc).
I have just completed the functions which shall update the users roles depending on a table which I have in my MySQL Database.
Since the entire discord bot is written in asynchronous code I want to stay with the schema which I already established.
I already read about asynchronous code and know that I have to use something like the `aiomysql` module for python.
Sadly the docs are not very beginner friendly and that's why I am asking my question here:

I wanna do something like this:

```
async def queryDB(query):
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  def test_example(query):
    conn = yield from aiomysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                       user='root', password='', db='mysql',
                                       loop=loop)

    cur = yield from conn.cursor()
    yield from cur.execute(query)
    print(cur.description)
    results = yield from cur.fetchall()
    yield from cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return results

  var = loop.run_until_complete(test_example(query))
  return var
```

As you can see I want the query to be modular and set the parameter in a function call. I want my results returned of course so I can work with it later.

This code keeps failing with the error code: `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` and I don't know how to fix this. There probably is an issue with how I deal with the loops and how I call my functions.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get a connection pool when the bot starts up and attach it to the bot.  Below is an example that runs whatever query it's given.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, is_owner

bot = Bot('!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                                       user='root', password='', db='mysql',
                                       loop=bot.loop)

@is_owner()  # Only bot owner can run this command
@bot.command()
async def query(ctx, *, q):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(q)
            res = await cur.fetchall()
            await ctx.send(str(res))

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There is a small typo in the query function tho.
You forgot the C in ```await cur.execute```.

Works like a charm tho

Comment: On the `async with pool.acquire() as conn:` line, `pool` needs to be `bot.pool`.